# Broken Software index, what do I do

Tags: 11.04, package-management

I tried to install libboost and it failed.  Now I'm getting the error that there are unmet dependencies and I cannot do anything involving upgrading or installing packages.
I run `sudo apt-get -f install` as recommended in the messages but I get the errors

```
root@IM-EPI140:~# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libboost1.42-dev
Suggested packages:
  libboost1.42-doc libboost-date-time1.42-dev libboost-filesystem1.42-dev
  libboost-graph1.42-dev libboost-iostreams1.42-dev libboost-math1.42-dev
  libboost-program-options1.42-dev libboost-python1.42-dev
  libboost-regex1.42-dev libboost-serialization1.42-dev
  libboost-signals1.42-dev libboost-system1.42-dev libboost-thread1.42-dev
  libboost-wave1.42-dev docbook-xsl fop
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libboost1.42-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/6,624 kB of archives.
After this operation, 68.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
dpkg: regarding .../libboost1.42-dev_1.42.0-4ubuntu2_amd64.deb containing libboost1.42-dev:
 libboost1.42-dev conflicts with libboost-dev (<< 1.35.0)
  libboost-dev:i386 (version 1.34.1-15ubuntu3) is present and unpacked but not configured.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libboost1.42-dev_1.42.0-4ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 conflicting packages - not installing libboost1.42-dev
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libboost1.42-dev_1.42.0-4ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a` ?

Comment: Just did, that did not help.

Comment: How about trying first a `sudo apt-get purge libboost-dev` and then an installation of `libboost-1.42-dev`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package manager says it right here :

- libboost1.42-dev conflicts with libboost-dev (<< 1.35.0)
  libboost-dev:i386 (version 1.34.1-15ubuntu3) is present and unpacked
  but not configured. dpkg: error processing
  /var/cache/apt/archives/libboost1.42-dev_1.42.0-4ubuntu2_amd64.deb
  (--unpack): conflicting packages - not installing libboost1.42-dev

  ---

There is a previous version installed. (1.35.0)  I would go into synaptic and uninstall that version first and then try again.

Comment: Removing through synaptic did the trick.