# Ubuntu update to 20.04 failed

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, updates

I'm trying to update an old Ubuntu from 16.04 to 22.04 LTS. I got from 16.04->18.04, but when I tried 18.04->20.04, the update aborted. The computer is using version 20.04 though.
I tried to use `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, but I got the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  argyll argyll-ref caribou cdbs comerr-dev dh-python dh-translations
  docutils-common fonts-font-awesome gcc-8-base:i386 gconf2 gir1.2-caribou-1.0
  gir1.2-gepub-0.6 gir1.2-gkbd-3.0 gir1.2-handy-0.0 gir1.2-harfbuzz-0.0
  gir1.2-mutter-2 gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 gir1.2-nmgtk-1.0
  gir1.2-tracker-1.0 gir1.2-xkl-1.0 gnome-icon-theme-symbolic
  gnome-shell-extension-prefs gnome-tweak-tool gnome-tweaks intltool jq
  krb5-multidev lib32gcc-s1 lib32gcc1 libamd2.4.1 libargon2-0 libarmadillo6
  libarmadillo8 libavcodec57 libavdevice-ffmpeg56 libavdevice57 libavfilter6
  libavformat57 libavresample3 libavutil55 libbind9-160 libblas-common
  libboost-date-time1.65.1 libboost-filesystem1.65.1 libboost-iostreams1.65.1
  libboost-locale1.65.1 libboost-log1.58.0 libboost-regex1.58.0
  libboost-system1.65.1 libboost-thread1.58.0 libboost-thread1.65.1
  libcamd2.4.1 libcapnp-0.6.1 libcaribou-common libcaribou0 libccolamd2.9.1
  libcdio17 libcholmod3.0.6 libchromaprint0 libclick-0.4-0
  libclutter-gst-2.0-0 libcontent-hub0 libcryptui0a libcue1 libcwidget3v5
  libdap17v5 libdleyna-core-1.0-3 libdns-export1100 libdns1100
  libdouble-conversion1 libdvdread4 libenca0 libevent-2.1-6 libffi6:i386
  libfile-which-perl libfluidsynth1 libftdi1 libgdbm5 libgegl-0.3-0
  libgeos-3.5.0 libgeos-3.6.2 libgeotiff2 libgepub-0.6-0 libgflags2.2
  libgflags2v5 libglade2-0 libgmime-3.0-0 libgnome-desktop-3-17
  libgnuinet-java libgnumail-java libgoogle-glog0v5 libgpm2:i386
  libgraphite2-dev libgspell-1-1 libgssdp-1.0-3 libgssrpc4 libgtkmm-2.4-1v5
  libgupnp-1.0-4 libgweather-3-15 libhardware2 libharfbuzz-dev
  libharfbuzz-gobject0 libhdf5-10 libhdf5-cpp-11 libhmsbeagle1v5
  libhunspell-1.6-0 libhybris libhybris-common1 libicu-le-hb-dev libicu-le-hb0
  libiculx60 libip4tc0 libip6tc0 libiptc0 libiptcdata0 libirs160
  libisc-export169 libisc169 libisccc160 libisccfg160 libisl19 libjasper-dev
  libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 libjq1 libjs-modernizr libjson-c3 libjte1
  libkadm5clnt-mit11 libkadm5clnt-mit9 libkadm5srv-mit11 libkdb5-9
  liblibertine1 libllvm10 libllvm10:i386 libllvm6.0 liblouis14 liblouisutdml8
  liblttng-ust-ctl2 liblttng-ust-ctl4 liblttng-ust0 liblua5.1-0 liblwres160
  libmagickcore-6.q16-3 libmagickcore-6.q16-3-extra libmagickwand-6.q16-3
  libmedia1 libmimic0 libmozjs-24-0v5 libmozjs-52-0 libmutter-2-0 libmysofa0
  libmysqlclient20 libncursesw5:i386 libnetcdf11 libntfs-3g88 libonig4
  libonig5 libopencv-calib3d2.4v5 libopencv-contrib2.4v5
  libopencv-features2d2.4v5 libopencv-flann2.4v5 libopencv-legacy2.4v5
  libopencv-ml2.4v5 libopencv-objdetect2.4v5 libopencv-video2.4v5
  liborcus-0.13-0 libosinfo-1.0-0 libperl5.26 libpoppler73 libpostproc54
  libprocps6 libproj12 libproj9 libprotobuf-lite10 libprotobuf10
  libpython-all-dev libpython3.6 libpython3.6-minimal libpython3.6-stdlib
  libraw16 libreadline7 librsync1 libruby2.5 libsane1 libsdl1.2debian
  libsodium18 libsrtp0 libsuperlu4 libswresample2 libswscale4 libtagc0
  libtinfo-dev libtinfo5:i386 libtracker-control-1.0-0 libtracker-miner-1.0-0
  libubuntu-app-launch2 libubuntu-download-manager-client1
  libubuntu-download-manager-common1 libudm-common1 libumfpack5.7.1 liburcu4
  liburcu6 libuutil1linux libvpx5 libwayland-server0:i386 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0
  libwildmidi1 libwxgtk3.0-0v5 libx264-152 libx265-146 libxcb-xf86dri0
  libxdamage1:i386 libxerces-c3.1 libxmlb1 libzfs2linux libzpool2linux
  linux-headers-4.15.0-140 linux-headers-4.15.0-140-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-210 linux-headers-4.4.0-210-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-140-generic linux-image-4.4.0-210-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-140-generic linux-modules-4.4.0-210-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-140-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-142-generic linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-210-generic
  nplan openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jdk-headless osinfo-db oxideqt-codecs-extra
  plainbox-provider-checkbox plainbox-provider-resource-generic pyotherside
  python-alabaster python-all python-all-dev python-asn1crypto python-babel
  python-babel-localedata python-cairo python-certifi python-cffi-backend
  python-chardet python-crypto python-cryptography python-dbus python-docutils
  python-entrypoints python-enum34 python-fasteners python-glade2
  python-gobject-2 python-gtk2 python-idna python-imagesize python-imaging
  python-ipaddress python-jinja2 python-keyring python-libxml2 python-lockfile
  python-markupsafe python-monotonic python-ndg-httpsclient python-openssl
  python-pip-whl python-pyasn1 python-pyatspi python-pygments python-requests
  python-roman python-scour python-secretstorage python-typing python-urllib3
  python-wheel python-xdg python3-alabaster python3-asn1crypto python3-babel
  python3-bs4 python3-checkbox-support python3-docutils python3-feedparser
  python3-guacamole python3-html5lib python3-imagesize python3-jinja2
  python3-lxml python3-oauth python3-packaging python3-padme python3-plainbox
  python3-pyasn1 python3-pycurl python3-pygments python3-pyparsing
  python3-roman python3-scour python3-soupsieve python3-sphinx
  python3-webencodings python3-xlsxwriter python3-zope.interface python3.5
  python3.5-minimal python3.6 python3.6-minimal qml-module-io-thp-pyotherside
  qml-module-qtwebkit qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-content1 ruby2.5 scour
  seahorse-daemon sphinx-common sphinx-rtd-theme-common unity-lens-photos
  unity-scope-calculator unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks
  unity-scope-colourlovers unity-scope-devhelp unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks
  unity-scope-gdrive unity-scope-manpages unity-scope-openclipart
  unity-scope-texdoc unity-scope-tomboy unity-scope-virtualbox
  unity-scope-yelp unity-scope-zotero unixodbc x11proto-input-dev
  x11proto-kb-dev xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-16.04
  xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-16.04
  xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-16.04
  xserver-xorg-video-qxl-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-vesa-hwe-16.04
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  apparmor libreoffice-common
Suggested packages:
  apparmor-profiles-extra apparmor-utils
Recommended packages:
  python3-uno
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apparmor libreoffice-common
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
19 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/24.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 22.5 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 574495 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../apparmor_2.13.3-7ubuntu5.2_amd64.deb ...
rm: cannot remove '/etc/apparmor.d/cache/e10c1cf9.0': Is a directory
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/apparmor_2.13.3-7ubuntu5.
2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new apparmor package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit sta
tus 1
dpkg: regarding .../libreoffice-common_1%3a6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8_all.deb contai
ning libreoffice-common:
 libreoffice-common conflicts with apparmor (<< 2.13.1~)
  apparmor (version 2.12-4ubuntu5.3) is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a6.
4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8_all.deb (--unpack):
 conflicting packages - not installing libreoffice-common
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apparmor_2.13.3-7ubuntu5.2_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I try `sudo apt autoremove`, I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmutter-6-0 : Breaks: apparmor (< 2.13.3-5~) but 2.12-4ubuntu5.3 is installed
 libreoffice-calc : Breaks: libreoffice-common (< 1:6.4.2~rc1~) but 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13 is installed
 libreoffice-common : Breaks: libreoffice-core (>= 1:6.1~) but 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 is installed
                      Breaks: libreoffice-style-breeze (>= 1:6.1~) but 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 is installed
                      Breaks: libreoffice-style-galaxy (>= 1:6.1~) but 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 is installed
                      Breaks: libreoffice-style-tango (>= 1:6.1~) but 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 is installed
                      Recommends: python3-uno (>= 4.4.0~beta2) but it is not installed
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libreoffice-common (> 1:6.4.7) but 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13 is installed
 libreoffice-draw : Breaks: libreoffice-common (< 1:6.4.2~rc1~) but 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13 is installed
 libreoffice-help-common : Breaks: libreoffice-common (< 1:6.3.0) but 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13 is installed
 libreoffice-help-en-us : Depends: libreoffice-common (>= 1:6.1.0~) but 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13 is installed
 libreoffice-impress : Breaks: libreoffice-common (< 1:6.4.2~rc1~) but 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13 is installed
 libreoffice-math : Breaks: libreoffice-common (< 1:6.4.2~rc1~) but 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13 is installed
 libreoffice-writer : Breaks: libreoffice-common (< 1:6.4.2~rc1~) but 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I try `sudo apt remove libreoffice`, it says:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'libreoffice' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmutter-6-0 : Breaks: apparmor (< 2.13.3-5~) but 2.12-4ubuntu5.3 is to be installed
 libreoffice-calc : Breaks: libreoffice-common (< 1:6.4.2~rc1~) but 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13 is to be installed
 libreoffice-common : Breaks: libreoffice-core (>= 1:6.1~) but 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 is to be installed
                      Breaks: libreoffice-style-breeze (>= 1:6.1~) but 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 is to be installed
                      Breaks: libreoffice-style-galaxy (>= 1:6.1~) but 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 is to be installed
                      Breaks: libreoffice-style-tango (>= 1:6.1~) but 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 is to be installed
                      Recommends: python3-uno (>= 4.4.0~beta2) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libreoffice-common (> 1:6.4.7) but 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13 is to be installed
 libreoffice-draw : Breaks: libreoffice-common (< 1:6.4.2~rc1~) but 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13 is to be installed
 libreoffice-help-common : Breaks: libreoffice-common (< 1:6.3.0) but 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13 is to be installed
 libreoffice-help-en-us : Depends: libreoffice-common (>= 1:6.1.0~) but 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13 is to be installed
 libreoffice-impress : Breaks: libreoffice-common (< 1:6.4.2~rc1~) but 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13 is to be installed
 libreoffice-math : Breaks: libreoffice-common (< 1:6.4.2~rc1~) but 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13 is to be installed
 libreoffice-writer : Breaks: libreoffice-common (< 1:6.4.2~rc1~) but 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

And when I try `sudo apt remove apparmor`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-calc : Breaks: libreoffice-common (< 1:6.4.2~rc1~) but 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13 is to be installed
 libreoffice-common : Breaks: libreoffice-core (>= 1:6.1~) but 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 is to be installed
                      Breaks: libreoffice-style-breeze (>= 1:6.1~) but 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 is to be installed
                      Breaks: libreoffice-style-galaxy (>= 1:6.1~) but 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 is to be installed
                      Breaks: libreoffice-style-tango (>= 1:6.1~) but 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 is to be installed
                      Recommends: python3-uno (>= 4.4.0~beta2) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libreoffice-common (> 1:6.4.7) but 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13 is to be installed
 libreoffice-draw : Breaks: libreoffice-common (< 1:6.4.2~rc1~) but 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13 is to be installed
 libreoffice-help-common : Breaks: libreoffice-common (< 1:6.3.0) but 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13 is to be installed
 libreoffice-help-en-us : Depends: libreoffice-common (>= 1:6.1.0~) but 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13 is to be installed
 libreoffice-impress : Breaks: libreoffice-common (< 1:6.4.2~rc1~) but 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13 is to be installed
 libreoffice-math : Breaks: libreoffice-common (< 1:6.4.2~rc1~) but 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13 is to be installed
 libreoffice-writer : Breaks: libreoffice-common (< 1:6.4.2~rc1~) but 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13 is to be installed
 snapd : Depends: apparmor (>= 2.10.95-0ubuntu2.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So there seems to be a loop between `apparmor` and `libreoffice`.

I've also tried `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`, which go through but don't fix anything. `sudo dpkg --configure -a` comes up with the following error:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-style-galaxy:
 libreoffice-common (1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13) breaks libreoffice-style-galaxy (>= 1:6.1~) and is broken due to postinst failure.
  Version of libreoffice-style-galaxy to be configured is 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-style-galaxy (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-style-tango:
 libreoffice-common (1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13) breaks libreoffice-style-tango (>= 1:6.1~) and is broken due to postinst failure.
  Version of libreoffice-style-tango to be configured is 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-style-tango (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-common:
 libreoffice-common depends on libreoffice-style-tango; however:
  Package libreoffice-style-tango is not configured yet.
 libreoffice-writer (1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8) breaks libreoffice-common (<< 1:6.4.2~rc1~) and is unpacked but not configured.
  Version of libreoffice-common to be configured is 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13.
 libreoffice-math (1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8) breaks libreoffice-common (<< 1:6.4.2~rc1~) and is unpacked but not configured.
  Version of libreoffice-common to be configured is 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13.
 libreoffice-impress (1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8) breaks libreoffice-common (<< 1:6.4.2~rc1~) and is unpacked but not configured.
  Version of libreoffice-common to be configured is 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13.
 libreoffice-help-common (1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8) breaks libreoffice-common (<< 1:6.3.0) and is unpacked but not configured.
  Version of libreoffice-common to be configured is 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13.
 libreoffice-draw (1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8) breaks libreoffice-common (<< 1:6.4.2~rc1~) and is unpacked but not configured.
  Version of libreoffice-common to be configured is 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13.
 libreoffice-calc (1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8) breaks libreoffice-common (<< 1:6.4.2~rc1~) and is unpacked but not configured.
  Version of libreoffice-common to be configured is 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-style-breeze:
 libreoffice-style-breeze depends on libreoffice-style-tango; however:
  Package libreoffice-style-tango is not configured yet.
 libreoffice-common (1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13) breaks libreoffice-style-breeze (>= 1:6.1~) and is broken due to postinst failure.
  Version of libreoffice-style-breeze to be configured is 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-style-breeze (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-help-en-us:
 libreoffice-help-en-us depends on libreoffice-common (>= 1:6.1.0~); however:
  Version of libreoffice-common on system is 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13.
 libreoffice-help-en-us depends on libreoffice-l10n-en-us; however:
  Package libreoffice-l10n-en-us is not installed.
  Package libreoffice-common which provides libreoffice-l10n-en-us is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-help-en-us (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-core:
 libreoffice-core depends on libreoffice-common (>> 1:6.4.7); however:
  Version of libreoffice-common on system is 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13.
 libreoffice-common (1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13) breaks libreoffice-core (>= 1:6.1~) and is broken due to postinst failure.
  Version of libreoffice-core to be configured is 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-calc:
 libreoffice-calc depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-calc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-style-elementary:
 libreoffice-style-elementary depends on libreoffice-style-tango; however:
  Package libreoffice-style-tango is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-style-elementary (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-math:
 libreoffice-math depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-math (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-gtk3:
 libreoffice-gtk3 depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-gtk3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-writer:
 libreoffice-writer depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-writer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-pdfimport:
 libreoffice-pdfimport depends on libreoffice-common (>= 1:5.4~); however:
  Package libreoffice-common is not configured yet.
 libreoffice-pdfimport depends on libreoffice-core (>= 1:5.4~); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-pdfimport (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-draw:
 libreoffice-draw depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-draw (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer:
 libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer depends on libreoffice-core (>> 1:6.3.0~rc1~); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-help-common:
 libreoffice-help-common depends on libreoffice-common; however:
  Package libreoffice-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-help-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-gnome:
 libreoffice-gnome depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-gnome (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-impress:
 libreoffice-impress depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
 libreoffice-impress depends on libreoffice-draw (= 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8); however:
  Package libreoffice-draw is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-impress (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-base-core:
 libreoffice-base-core depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8) | libreoffice-core-nogui (= 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
  Package libreoffice-core-nogui is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-base-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-ogltrans:
 libreoffice-ogltrans depends on libreoffice-impress (>= 1:6.2.0~beta1~); however:
  Package libreoffice-impress is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-ogltrans (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libreoffice-style-galaxy
 libreoffice-style-tango
 libreoffice-common
 libreoffice-style-breeze
 libreoffice-help-en-us
 libreoffice-core
 libreoffice-calc
 libreoffice-style-elementary
 libreoffice-math
 libreoffice-gtk3
 libreoffice-writer
 libreoffice-pdfimport
 libreoffice-draw
 libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer
 libreoffice-help-common
 libreoffice-gnome
 libreoffice-impress
 libreoffice-base-core
 libreoffice-ogltrans
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm fairly new to Linux, so I'm not sure how to approach this.

Comment: Looks like your release-upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 failed. A successful upgrade includes autoremove, so it doesn't leave orphans behind. For most users, a complete reinstall would be faster, simpler, and less risky. Is there a reason you MUST do sequential release-upgrades? Alternately, how many days do you want to spend learning how to troubleshoot apt error messages?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Broken Software index, what do I do](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54921/broken-software-index-what-do-i-do)

Comment: There was not a reason I just didn't realize there was another way. I've re downloaded Ubuntu software (at the latest version) so the problem has been fixed! Thank you so much for the suggestions!

Answer (score 11):

`sudo rm -rf /etc/apparmor.d/cache/` fixed my problem

Comment: I would buy you a beer! :)

Comment: Fixed my issue upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04 even though it wasn't libreoffice causing it to begin with.

Answer (score -1):

Additional fix from gr8: Remove AppArmor cache:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/apparmor.d/cache/
```

Update package lists and fix broken installs:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Continue with the rest of the commands if needed. Thanks to gr8 for the guide!